# How to specify JSON-formatted string in Cloudformation?

Tags: json, aws-cloudformation

I have the following resource on my CloudFormation template to create a rule to run a Lambda function, from the AWS documentation:

```
  "ScheduledRule": {
    "Type": "AWS::Events::Rule",
    "Properties": {
    "Description": "ScheduledRule",
    "ScheduleExpression": "rate(5 minutes)",
    "State": "ENABLED",
    "Targets": [{
      "Arn": { "Fn::GetAtt": ["myLambda", "Arn"] },
      "Id": "TargetFunctionV1"
    }]
    }
  }
```

I would like to specify the Input:

```
{
  "Arn" : String,
  "Id" : String,
  "Input" : String,
  "InputPath" : String
}
```

and Input is a JSON-formatted text string that is passed to the target. This value overrides the matched event.

I would like my JSON formatted text to be:

```
{
  "mykey1": "Some Value"
}
```

I do not know how to specify it in the Input, when I put:

```
  "ScheduledRule": {
    "Type": "AWS::Events::Rule",
    "Properties": {
    "Description": "ScheduledRule",
    "ScheduleExpression": "rate(5 minutes)",
    "State": "ENABLED",
    "Targets": [{
      "Arn": { "Fn::GetAtt": ["myLambda", "Arn"] },
      "Id": "TargetFunctionV1",
      "Input": { "mykey1": "Some Value" }
    }]
    }
  }
```

I will get error:

> Value of property Input must be of type String

How should I specify it correctly?

Comment: Feature request: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/78

Answer (score 26):

I would use YAML as it is easier and more readable:

```
Input:
  !Sub |
    {
        mykey1: "${myKey}"
    }
```

Comment: Does this work in Cloudformation template as well @Pau? Any requirements?

Comment: Yeah, It works. You just would use YAML instead of JSON.

Comment: This technique works well, you can simply define you json key/values without any of the json to string conversion. Read Mooncraters comment on the use of !Sub

Answer (score 21):

Found out the answer myself:

`"Input": "{ \"test\" : \"value11\", \"test2\" : \"value22\"}"`

Hope it helps someone else.

**Update:**

You basically use the result of JSON.Stringify() to get the string into "Input" field. Use online JSON.Stringify() like https://onlinetexttools.com/json-stringify-text

Comment: If you don't want to use the stringified string, which is hard to read, you can use the [`Fn::ToJsonString`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ToJsonString.html) Cloudformation transform 

It would look like:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::LanguageExtensions
[...]
 "Input":  { "Fn::ToJsonString": {
                 "mykey1": "Some Value"
                }}
```

Answer (score 12):

I wanted to expand on @Pau's answer. Basically if you use the `|` to say that the whole block below is to be treated as a raw string.

If you need to replace any variable in the JSON then you can use `Sub`, but if you don't have any variables, then you don't need `Sub`. An example would be:

```
Input:|
  {
    "jsonVar":"jsonVal",
    "jsonVar2" : "jsonVal2"
  }
```

You can later do `JSON.parse(<input-variable>)` to get the JSON object.

NOTE: Don't put commas at the end of the variables in JSON, if there is no next variable. Example :

```
Input:|
  {
    "jsonVar":"jsonVal",
    "jsonVar2" : "jsonVal2",
  }
```

This will cause JSON parsing errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing your CloudFormation scripts in yaml and finding it difficult to use a JSON string (such as a policy doc) the easiest way is to convert your JSON into yaml using an [online converter](https://www.json2yaml.com/)

```
ApiGatewayRestApi:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Description: API Gateway for some API
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - PRIVATE
      Name: MyAPIGateway 
      Policy: <Policy Doc >
```

Lets say the policy doc is as follows.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:ap-southeast-2:something/*",
        "Condition": {
            "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-abcd"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Using the converter you can convert the JSON into an identical yaml and use as follows.

```
ApiGatewayRestApi:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Description: API Gateway for some API
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - PRIVATE
      Name: MyAPIGateway 
      Policy: 
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal: "*"
          Action: execute-api:Invoke
          Resource: arn:aws:execute-api:ap-southeast-2:something/*
          Condition:
            ForAnyValue:StringEquals:
              aws:sourceVpce: vpce-abcd
```

Comment: It looks like he was asking how you pass JSON in a string field in a CFN template. It would need to be stringified, for example with the JavaScript function `JSON.Stringify()`

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend, I was looking for something like this. This is much more concise than using json inside a yaml file.

Comment: This is a beautiful answer that makes it not hurt at all to rewrite JSON policies to cloudformation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my similar YAML code for the "input" line.  It took me all day to figure out the syntax so I'm hoping this might help someone in the future.

```
Input: "{\"action\":[\"configure\"],\"mode\":[\"ec2\"],\"optionalConfigurationSource\":[\"ssm\"],\"optionalConfigurationLocation\":[\"AmazonCloudWatch-Baseline-Windows\"],\"optionalRestart\":[\"yes\"]}"
```