# Cloudformation KeyValuePair List as a parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

When creating ECS infrastructure we describe our [Task Definitions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html) with CloudFormation. We want to be able to dynamically pass environment variables as a parameter to the template. According to the docs, [Environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinition-environment) has a [KeyValuePair](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions-environment.html) type, but CloudFormation parameters do not have this type.
We can not hardcode Environment variables to the template, because this template is used as a nested stack so environment variables will be dynamically passed inside it.

The only possible way I see so far is to pass all arguments as a CommaDelimitedList, and then somehow parse and map it using [CloudFormation functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html). I can Fn::Split every entity in key and value, but how to dynamically build an array of KeyValuePair in CloudFormation?

Or maybe there is an easier way, and I'm missing something? Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: What client/service consumes the key pair from the environment?  How many keypairs need to be injected as parameters?

Comment: @RodrigoM, amount of key-value pairs are dynamic, but in our case, it is up to 20 environment variables. Those environment variables are being passed to Docker container if this is what you are asking for.

Comment: I was just wondering where in the process are they referenced. Are the values referred to in Docker file or in the run time application? both?

Comment: @RodrigoM In runtime application only, ECS is working with already baked dockerfiles and pass variables to containers

Comment: You could write a script that generates the CloudFormation template based on your required environment variables. That script can then use AWS API to also deploy the stack.

Comment: @kichik, this is the last resort if all other options fail, but probably I have no other choice.

Comment: @Ivan This is the exact problem I'm handling now, did you end up solving it?

Comment: @OmerH so we decided not to pass env. variables as a part of the template, instead, on every deployment we dynamically inject variables into the task definition. The reason behind that for is - our ECR repository is a part of the template as well, so by the time infrastructure is being provisioned the first time there is no docker image exists in the ECR, therefore there is no point in passing env. variables as well. Let me know if that makes sense

Comment: @Ivan, I understand but it's still not a solution for me. I'd like to do the deployments with CloudFormation, so when there's a new version of an application my CI server would simple update the stack's template with a new docker tag. This is why I want my environment variables to be part of it.

Comment: @OmerH i see your point. I can only suggest you to pre-process the template with your environment variables. (e.g. load the file and do string.replace for some placeholder). I haven't found other way. But anyway, updating ECS via Cloudformation is way slower and might have some side-effects, like recreating task/service for every deployment. I'd strongly suggest to use something like this instead - https://github.com/silinternational/ecs-deploy

Comment: @Ivan honestly I don't understand the need for an external tool. I'm doing it now with CloudFormation simply by updating the current stack and providing a different image and tag. It runs very fast.
My solution for the variables was to use the AWS parameter store and chamber (https://github.com/segmentio/chamber) for their delivery. works really well

Comment: Cool, I guess this is another way of doing this. I'm surprised that CloudFormation is working fine for updating image and tag. Does it create a new task revision now? Maybe they fixed this since the time I was trying this. Anyway, I'm happy you solved this, and thanks for posting your way of doing this @OmerH

Comment: Can we use JSON.Stringify() on the list and send it as a string parameter, as given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041209/how-to-specify-json-formatted-string-in-cloudformation?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late and you have already found a workaround. However, the following is the closest I came to solve this. Still not completely dynamic as expected parameters have to be defined as placeholders. Therefore the maximum number of environment variables expected should be known.

The answer is based on this [blog](https://garbe.io/blog/2017/07/17/cloudformation-hacks/). All credits to the author.

```yaml
Parameters:
  EnvVar1:
    Type: String
    Description: A possible environment variable to be passed on to the container definition.
      Should be a key-value pair combined with a ':'. E.g. 'envkey:envval'
    Default: ''
  EnvVar2:
    Type: String
    Description: A possible environment variable to be passed on to the container definition.
      Should be a key-value pair combined with a ':'. E.g. 'envkey:envval'
    Default: ''
  EnvVar3:
    Type: String
    Description: A possible environment variable to be passed on to the container definition.
      Should be a key-value pair combined with a ':'. E.g. 'envkey:envval'
    Default: ''
Conditions:
  Env1Exist: !Not [ !Equals [!Ref EnvVar1, '']]
  Env2Exist: !Not [ !Equals [!Ref EnvVar2, '']]
  Env3Exist: !Not [ !Equals [!Ref EnvVar3, '']]
Resources:
  TaskDefinition:
    ContainerDefinitions:
      -
         Environment:
           - !If
             - Env1Exist
             -
               Name: !Select [0, !Split [":", !Ref EnvVar1]]
               Value: !Select [1, !Split [":", !Ref EnvVar1]]
             - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
           - !If
             - Env2Exist
             -
               Name: !Select [0, !Split [":", !Ref EnvVar2]]
               Value: !Select [1, !Split [":", !Ref EnvVar2]]
             - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
           - !If
             - Env3Exist
             -
               Name: !Select [0, !Split [":", !Ref EnvVar3]]
               Value: !Select [1, !Split [":", !Ref EnvVar3]]
             - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using the EC2 Parameter Store to create secured key/value pairs, which is supported in CloudFormation, and can be integrated with ECS environments.

[AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html)

> AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store provides secure, hierarchical
>   storage for configuration data management and secrets management. You
>   can store data such as passwords, database strings, and license codes
>   as parameter values. You can store values as plain text or encrypted
>   data. You can then reference values by using the unique name that you
>   specified when you created the parameter. Highly scalable, available,
>   and durable, Parameter Store is backed by the AWS Cloud. Parameter
>   Store is offered at no additional charge.

While Parameter Store has great security features for storing application secrets, it can also be used to store nonsensitive application strings such as public keys, environment settings, license codes, etc.

And it is supported directly by CloudFormation, allowing you to easily capture, store and manage application configuration strings which can be accessed by ECS.
This template allows  you provide the Parameter store key values at stack creation time via the console or CLI:

```
Description: Simple SSM parameter example
Parameters:
  pSMTPServer:
    Description: SMTP Server URL eg [email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com]:587
    Type: String
    NoEcho: false
  SMTPServer:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties: 
      Name: my-smtp-server
      Type: String
      Value: !Ref pSMTPServer
```

Any AWS runtime environment (EC2, ECS, Lambda) can easily securely retrieve the values. From the console side, there is great Parameter manager interface that maintains parameter version history. Its intergated with IAM, so permissions are controlled with standard IAM policy syntax:

```
{
    "Action": [
        "ssm:GetParameterHistory",
        "ssm:GetParameter",
        "ssm:GetParameters",
        "ssm:GetParametersByPath"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ssm:us-west-2:555513456471:parameter/smtp-server"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow"
},
{
    "Action": [
        "kms:Decrypt"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:555513456471:key/36235f94-19b5-4649-84e0-978f52242aa0a"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow"
}
```

Finally, this [blog article](https://www.whaletech.co/2017/08/01/Secure-Credentials-for-ECS-Tasks.html) shows a technique to read the permissions into a Dockerfile at runtime. They suggest a secure way to handle environment variables in Docker with AWS Parameter Store. For reference, I am including their Dockerfile here:

```
FROM grafana/grafana:master

RUN curl -L -o /bin/aws-env https://github.com/Droplr/aws-env/raw/master/bin/aws-env-linux-amd64 && \
  chmod +x /bin/aws-env

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "eval $(/bin/aws-env) && /run.sh"]
```

With that invocation, each of the parameters are available as an environment variable in the container. You app may or may not need a wrapper to read the parameters from the environment variables.

Comment: It does not really solve the problem of inserting a list of parameters into the template, does it? I need not only to pass env variable values, but keys as well

Comment: Well yes you can include 20 parameters in a template of course.  Is that what you mean?  What type of keys?  Its a general parameter store, so it can store anything.  We use them to store ssh keys, among other types of data

Comment: They are equal in function to the TaskDefinition ContainerDefinition KeyValue pairs you mentioned needing in CloudFormation.  SSM paramters are in CloudFormation today. You can also refer to the values in other stacks by using Fn::GetAtt(parameter,'value').  Seems like it should fit your given requirements no?

Comment: KeyValuePair has 'Key' and 'Value' properties. I need to insert not only 'Value' but also 'Key'. And amount KeyValuePairs is not known when you write a template, they all dynamic. So the whole array of KeyValuePairs must be inserted. Is that explains my problem? Maybe I was not clear enough in the initial questions.

Comment: To be fair I think @rodrigo-m is right in that using external config service like parameter store allows you to lookup required config values as needed. If you don't want to build the lookup into your container you could use a sidecar container to do that and link to your primary container.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem ,I needed to create a lambda resource with environment variables.
We decided to fix initial set of environment variable and keys name are also decided in advance.
So I added four parameters , and used Ref for values while keeping fixed keys name.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way too - which may sound overkill but it allows to put whatever env. to the function you wish, no need to "predefine" how many env. variables, only restriction in sample below - can not use `::::` or `||||` inside value of the key. Key can't have such symbols by AWS docs already.

Gameplan:

Make an inline CF Lambda Function with code which accepts all env in any format you wish as a string and uses any code you want to use inside that function (i use JS with NodeJS env) and while it's your code, parse how you wish that string passing in and use aws-sdk to update the function. Call function once inside the CF template.

In this sample you pass in env as such string:

`key1::::value1||||key2::::value2` If you need to use `::::` or `||||` in your value, of course update to some other divider.

Not big fan of running lambda for such task, yet i want to have option of passing in virtually any env. to the CF template and this works.

```
  LambdaToSetEnvRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLambdaInsightsExecutionRolePolicy
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: cloudwatch-logs
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
                  - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
                  - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
                Resource:
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:logs:*:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:*:*"
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:logs:*:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/lambda-insights:*"
        - PolicyName: trigger-lambda-by-cloud-events
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration'
                Resource:
                  - !GetAtt OriginalLambda.Arn
      Tags:
        - { Key: managed-by, Value: !Ref AWS::StackId }
  LambdaToSetEnv:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          const response = require('cfn-response');
          const aws = require('aws-sdk');
          exports.handler = (event, context) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify({event, context}));
            try {
              if (event.RequestType === "Delete") {
                response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, {RequestType: event.RequestType});
              } else {
                const client = new aws.Lambda({apiVersion: '2015-03-31'});
                const Variables = {
                  "All": process.env.FunctionEnvVariables,
                };
                console.log('process.env.FunctionEnvVariables: ', process.env.FunctionEnvVariables);
                if(process.env.FunctionEnvVariables){
                  process.env.FunctionEnvVariables.split('||||').forEach((pair) => {
                    if(pair && pair.trim() !== ''){
                      Variables[pair.split('::::')[0]] = pair.split('::::')[1];
                    }
                  })
                }
                const result = client.updateFunctionConfiguration({ FunctionName: process.env.LambdaToUpdateArn, Environment: { Variables } }, function (error, data){
                  console.log('data: ', data);
                  console.log('error: ', error);
                  if(error){
                    console.error(error);
                    response.send(event, context, response.ERROR, {});      
                  } else {
                    response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, {});
                  }
                });
              }
            } catch (e) {
              response.send(event, context, response.ERROR, e.stack);
            }
          }
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaToSetEnvRole.Arn
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Timeout: '300'
      Environment:
        Variables:
          LambdaToUpdateArn: !GetAtt OriginalLambda.Arn
          FunctionEnvVariables: !Ref FunctionEnvVariables
  LambdaCall:
    DependsOn:
      - OriginalLambda
      - LambdaToSetEnv
    Type: Custom::LambdaCallout
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt LambdaToSetEnv.Arn
```