# Passing a list of KeyValuePairs to AWS Cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I am building a cloudformation template for a bunch (~75) of microservices running in ECS. There is a top-level template that includes all the microservices as nested stacks. Instead of creating dozens of different template files for each of the services I would like all of the microservices to use the same `microservice.yaml` template and use parameters to define which microservice to run.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Deploy a service into an ECS cluster
Parameters:
  ServiceName:
    Type: String
  ImageUrl:
    Type: String
  LogLevel:
    Type: String
    Default: debug
  NodeEnv:
    Type: String
    Default: integration

Resources:
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      RequiresCompatibilities: 
        - EC2
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: !Ref 'ServiceName'
          Image: !Ref 'ImageUrl'
          Environment:
            - Name: LOG_LEVEL
              Value: !Ref 'LogLevel'
            - Name: NODE_ENV
              Value: !Ref 'NodeEnv'

  Service:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      ServiceName: !Ref 'ServiceName'
      Cluster: !ImportValue production-infrastructure:ECSClusterName
      DesiredCount: 1
      TaskDefinition: !Ref 'TaskDefinition'
```

In `master.yaml` I will list all of the services like so:

```
FooBarMicroservice:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
  Properties:
    Parameters:
      ServiceName: fooBarMicroservice
      ImageUrl: !Join ['' , [ !Ref 'ECRHost', '/fooBarMicroservice']]
    TemplateURL: "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates/microservice.yaml"
```

The problem is that many of the microservices require additional unique environment variables. What I've done until now is add all the possible variables to the one template with default values of `''`. But now the `TaskDefinition` is beginning to look like this:

```
TaskDefinition:
  Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
  Properties:
    RequiresCompatibilities: 
      - EC2
    ContainerDefinitions:
      - Name: !Ref 'ServiceName'
        Image: !Ref 'ImageUrl'
        Environment:
          - Name: LOG_LEVEL
            Value: !Ref 'LogLevel'
          - Name: NODE_ENV
            Value: !Ref 'NodeEnv'
          - Name: SMTP
            Value: !Ref 'SMTP'
          - Name: ACME_CLIENT_ID
            Value: !Ref 'AcmeClientId'
          - Name: ACME_SECRET
            Value: !Ref 'AcmeSecret'
          - Name: ACME_TIMEOUT
            Value: !Ref 'AcmeTimeout'
          - Name: FOO_WEBHOOK_ROUTE
            Value: !Ref 'FooWebhookRoute'
          - Name: EXPIRES_IN
            Value: !Ref 'expiresIn'
          ...
          ...
```

For any given microservice, most of those are just empty environment variables. This is becoming very unwieldy and confusing.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to pass a list of KeyValuesPairs to the `microservice.yaml` with all of the unique environment variables. Something like this (that does not work):

```
FooBarMicroservice:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
  Properties:
    Parameters:
      ServiceName: fooBarMicroservice
      ImageUrl: !Join ['' , [ !Ref 'ECRHost', '/fooBarMicroservice']]
      Env:
        - Name: ACME_CLIENT_ID
          Value: 'AE4051DE41'
        - Name: ACME_SECRET
          Value: 'TdUGm6GR>nQp|q<'
    TemplateURL: "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates/microservice.yaml"
```

and then join the `!Ref Env` list with the existing list of common env variables.

I have searched high and low but have been unable to find a viable solution. The closest reference is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47821408/cloudformation-keyvaluepair-list-as-a-parameter) almost two years ago with no relevant answer.

Comment: Are you using sam deploy cli?

Comment: @AssaelAzran Using the regular aws cli. `aws cloudformation create-stack`. Would using sam help?

Comment: I was able to inject env configuration json to my yaml using the command "sam deploy --parameter-overide"

Comment: I don't think it's possible with CF only. What we did to solve this kind of problem is to template the CF for microservice, then add the step to pre-process the template with jinja library. Hence, each microservice will have its own `TaskDefinition` with its own env variables.

Comment: @Apolozeus yep, thats kind of what I ended up doing. Wrote a script to generate each service's template.

Comment: Have you tried passing an environment file? 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinition-environmentfiles

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but did you have a look at this: https://garbe.io/blog/2017/07/17/cloudformation-hacks/?