# How to format parameter of data type JSON in a AWS CloudFormation YAML template?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sagemaker

The YAML template [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sagemaker-model-containerdefinition.html) for the AWS CloudFormation `AWS::SageMaker::Model` `ContainerDefinition` specifies that `Environment` is of type JSON. I can't work out how to submit JSON in my YAML template that does not cause a "CREATE_FAILED Internal Failure" after running a deploy with the below command.

```bash
aws cloudformation deploy --stack-name test1 --template-file test-template-export.yml
```

test-template-export.yml

```
Description: Example yaml

Resources:
  Model:
    Type: AWS::SageMaker::Model
    Properties:
      Containers:
      - ModelPackageName: arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-1:123456789123:model-package/name/25
      - Environment: '{"SAGEMAKER_CONTAINER_LOG_LEVEL": "20"}'
      ExecutionRoleArn: arn:aws:iam::123456789123:role/service-role/AmazonSageMakerServiceCatalogProductsUseRole
```

I have also tried the below formats as well and still no luck.

```
Containers:
- ModelPackageName: arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-1:123456789123:model-package/name/25
  Environment: '{"SAGEMAKER_CONTAINER_LOG_LEVEL": "20"}'
```

--

```
Containers:
- ModelPackageName: arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-1:123456789123:model-package/name/25
- Environment: | 
         {
            "SAGEMAKER_CONTAINER_LOG_LEVEL": "20"
          }
```

--

```
Containers:
- ModelPackageName: arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-1:123456789123:model-package/name/25
- Environment:
  - SAGEMAKER_CONTAINER_LOG_LEVEL: "20"
```

Running without Environment deploys fine.

I have tried everything in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041209/how-to-specify-json-formatted-string-in-cloudformation)
How do I format this `Environment` argument?

My version of aws cli is "aws-cli/2.4.10 Python/3.8.8"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi when you see JSON format think more dict.
So write it like this:

```
Containers:
- ModelPackageName: arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-1:123456789123:model-package/name/25
  Environment:
     SAGEMAKER_CONTAINER_LOG_LEVEL: 20
```

For IAM Policies the `PolicyDocument` is JSON type and this is how AWS do it in their exemple:

```
Type: 'AWS::IAM::Policy'
Properties:
  PolicyName: CFNUsers
  PolicyDocument:
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - 'cloudformation:Describe*'
          - 'cloudformation:List*'
          - 'cloudformation:Get*'
        Resource: '*'
  Groups:
    - !Ref CFNUserGroup
```

Comment: Thanks, this has changed my error message so at least that is some progress. Message is now  "CREATE_FAILED Model can not be null". Again this still works without environment being specifies which is what is confusing me

Comment: I see that ContainerDefinition is a list of configs. So you should remove the "-" before Environment. Because now it 2 different configs. I edit my answer so it is correct.

Comment: That works correctly now thanks. I was failing to understand that more than one container could be specified so a new list item is interpreted as another ContainerDefinition.