AWS Serverless DMS - ReportingConfig setup - issue in providing table mapping in JSON via cloud formation
i'm tyring to write a cloud formation script for creating reportingConfig resource for serverless DMS replication. i'm following AWS documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dms-replicationconfig.html
sample below:
Resources:
  DMSReplicationConfig:
    Type: 'AWS::DMS::ReplicationConfig'
    Properties:
      ComputeConfig:
        AvailabilityZone: 'multi'
        MinCapacityUnits: 2
        MaxCapacityUnits: 8
        ReplicationSubnetGroupId: 'default-vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        VpcSecurityGroupIds: 
          - 'sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      SourceEndpointArn: !Ref DmsSourceEndpoint
      TargetEndpointArn: !Ref DMSTargetEndpoint
      ReplicationType: 'full-load-and-cdc'
      TableMappings: |
        {
          "rules": [
            {
              "rule-type": "selection",
              "rule-id": "1",
              "rule-name": "SchemaMapping",
              "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "otp"
              },
              "rule-action": "include"
            },
            {
              "rule-type": "selection",
              "rule-id": "2",
              "rule-name": "TableMapping",
              "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "otp",
                "table-name": "audit"
              },
              "rule-action": "include"
            },
            {
              "rule-type": "selection",
              "rule-id": "3",
              "rule-name": "TableMapping",
              "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "otp",
                "table-name": "client"
              },
              "rule-action": "include"
            }
          ]
        }

but i'm getting error - [#/TableMappings: expected type: JSONObject, found: String]* **, while providing table mapping json
who to provide the table mapping in JSON to ensure it is accepted and works fine whie running the cloud formation script

The comment on one of the answers to this question indicates there is a helper function Fn::ToJsonString that could prove useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041209/how-to-specify-json-formatted-string-in-cloudformation
